# Time-discretization of dynamics of quadrotor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

A complete mathematical model of my [quadrotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadcopter) is presented through Euler's equation of motion, as follows.

$$ \begin{aligned} \ddot x &= \frac1m \left(\cos\phi \sin\theta \cos\psi - \sin\phi \sin\psi \right) U_{1} \\ \ddot y &= \frac1m \left (\cos\phi \sin\theta \sin\psi + \sin\phi \cos\psi \right) U_{1} \\ \ddot z &= −g + \frac1m \left (\cos\phi \cos\theta \right) U_{1} \\ \ddot \phi &= \frac{1}{I_{}} \left (\dot\theta \dot\psi (I_{z} - I_{y}) - J_{r} \dot\theta \Omega + lU_{2} \right) \\  \ddot \theta &= \frac{1}{I_{y}} \left( \dot\phi \dot\psi (I_{x} - I_{z}) + J_{r} \dot\phi \Omega + lU_{3} \right) \\ \ddot \psi &= \frac{1}{I_{z}} \left( \dot\phi \dot\theta (I_{y} - I_{x}) + U_{4} \right) \end{aligned} $$

where

- $U_{1}$ is the total thrust generated by the four rotors; $U_{2}$,$U_{3}$ and $U_{4}$ are the respective roll, pitch
  and yaw thrusts;
- $m$ denotes the mass of the quadrotor;
- $g$ denotes the acceleration due to gravity;
- $l$ represents the length from the motor to the center of mass;
- $J_{}$ signifies the moment of inertia;
- $I_{}$,$I_{}$ and $I_{}$ are the moments of inertia in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes for the whole body;
- $Ω$ is the overall residual propeller angular speed which is considered in the gyroscopic torque as the quadrotor rolls or pitches.

I am seeking guidance on transforming this system model to general normal form; specifically, I am thinking third-degree. Any guidance is appreciated, feel free to request further information. My ultimate goal is to achieve a form which meets the below discrete-time nonlinear uncertain system, which is in general normal form:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} x_{1} (k+1) = x_{2}(k)
\\\vdots
\\ x_{n-1} (k+1) = x_{n} (k)
\\ x_{n} (k+1) = f(x(k)) + g(x(k))u(k)
\\ y(k) = x_{1}(k)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Please specify what variables the terms in the equation are dependent on.

Comment: Thank you for seeking additional information. I have updated per your request.

Comment: I would like to retain the non-linearity. I realize the exact objective was not clear. Please see my post which includes an update of the goal. thank you

Comment: What you want seems to be a BDF - backward difference (quotient) formula - method of order 2 or 3. One could also argue that general linear multi-step methods fall into the presented scheme, except that they might also require a history for the control input. Do you use $x_1$ as output to simulate the time delay from control decoding to action?

Comment: $x$ is the state vector of the 12-dimensional first-order system. Then the most zero-stable linear multi-step method of the given structure with $n=3$ for $\dot x=f(x,u)$ is $$9x_4=3x_3+5x_2+x_1+16\Delta tf(x_3,u_3)$$ at index $k$, using $x_4(k)=x_3(k+1)$. It is second-order accurate. Usually multi-step methods have very small stability regions, meaning the time step $\Delta t$ needs to be small, inversely proportional to the eigenvalues of the Jacobian. These are mainly the eigenvalues for the part of the angular velocities.

Comment: Any progress???